# tkz-graph: Changing vertex from Simple to Normal

Tags: tkz-graph

Suppose I have a graph with vertex type "Simple". Is there any way to add a vertex with type "Normal" to the graph? The other order works just fine for me (Normal then Simple), but for some reason Simple then Normal doesn't work.

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: Is [tkz-graph-changing-individual-vertex-type](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45266/tkz-graph-changing-individual-vertex-type?rq=1) useful?